# libaio: getting event error code

Tags: c, linux

latest libaio API in linux (/usr/include/libaio.h) defines io_event like this:

```
struct io_event {
    PADDEDptr(void *data, __pad1);
    PADDEDptr(struct iocb *obj,  __pad2);
    PADDEDul(res,  __pad3);
    PADDEDul(res2, __pad4);
};
```

the PADDEDul resolves as:

```
#define PADDEDul(x, y)  unsigned long x; unsigned y
```

and all examples I have read say that if 'res' is negative then an error during system call happened and the res contains negative 'errno' variable. My question is, how can 'res' contain negative errno if it is declared as unsigned long long ? And if 'res' doesn't contain error code anymore where do I get it for a write or a read syscall?

Comment: This is a 'non-standard' (as in, not POSIX) version of AIO.  There's a useful looking document at Google Code called [AIO User Guide](http://code.google.com/p/kernel/wiki/AIOUserGuide).  However, it gives the type of the `res` field as `long long`, not `unsigned long`, so I can't tell what's happened since it was written (April 2012) to change the meaning.  OTOH, you may be able to track down the change on the Linux Kernel Mailing List archives (Google search terms 'linux kernel mailing list aio.h struct io_event' shows lots of recent (Dec 2012 - Feb 2013) activity.

Answer (score 0):

Please compare the definition from libaio with that in /usr/include/linux/aio_abi.h. You will find that 'res' and 'res2' are actually defined as signed integers there.

Here is a link of aio_abi.h for your convenience: http://kerneldox.com/kdox-linux/dd/db4/aio__abi_8h_source.html

Also, it is an acceptable option to wrap the kernel AIO APIs using syscall() from glibc. Learning these kernel APIs would be an impressive and profitable experience. To start, learn how nginx uses them.

Happy Hacking!